# admin passwd lost

Tags: password

y'all..well, i created an another user and then changed the password for it, but after i tried to log in by that new user account it said that password is wrong, yea seems like i have entered an wrong password with the beginning. oh also i set that account as an admin but disabled that account. i can't log in with that account also whenever i command on terminal it says something means like that it's not the admin account so you can't command anything.. what should i do to about my password? really need to fix it immediately. HELP me

Answer (score -3):

Tou should have a look at [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://goo.gl/gh0cC)

This could be helpful for you.

Laurent06000

Comment: This really should be a comment, as you aren't actually answering the question.